# RealmSwift: Retrieved Realm Object properties not populated to instance methods [Swift]

Tags: swift, realm

So I'm probably missing something something small but I created a realm object class and have a method to post that object to our backend.

When I fetch the objects, I can see the properties from the `Results` 
object.

If I call my post method, `self.myProperty` is either nil or whatever the default value I have set it.

**Generic Example:**

**Realm Object Class**

```
import SwiftyJSON

@objcMembers class Person:Object {

     var firstName:String = ""
     var lastName:String = ""

     func post() {
             print("First Name: ", self.firstName) // Prints "First Name: "
             print("Last Name: ", self.lastName) // Prints "Last Name: "
     }

}
```

**Retrieving Objects**

```
let people = realm.objects(Person.self)

print("First Name: ", people[0].firstName) // Prints "First Name: Evan"
print("Last Name: ", people[0].lastName) // Prints "Last Name: Stoddard"

people[0].post()
// Prints "First Name: "
// Prints "Last Name: "
```

So the retrieved object's properties are there when I access them outside of the confines of that object.  It seems like instance methods of the retrieved object don't work.

Again, I'm probably missing something super small but I can't seem to find any documentation relating to this issue.

**Edit:**
Made title more descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RealmSwift, properties should be marked as

```
@objc dynamic var ...
```

The @objc you have via the class annotation, but I'd add the dynamic modifier and retest.